# Error Installing pyaudio: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

Tags: python

After doing pip install pyaudio, It started collecting the package but suddenly it displayed Following error

This is the error I got in the terminal

```
PS C:\Users\user> pip install pyaudio   
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rqkofe07\\pyaudio_e2694735f99f47ea89c7f6ea2c6b1e31\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rqkofe07\\pyaudio_e2694735f99f47ea89c7f6ea2c6b1e31\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lmei1_wv\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rqkofe07\pyaudio_e2694735f99f47ea89c7f6ea2c6b1e31\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rqkofe07\\pyaudio_e2694735f99f47ea89c7f6ea2c6b1e31\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rqkofe07\\pyaudio_e2694735f99f47ea89c7f6ea2c6b1e31\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lmei1_wv\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1):

`extension error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

The error is in your traceback, you need Microsoft Visual C++.

In order to get C++ on your computer you will need to install Visual Studio using the link in the error code: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

While the solution by @William will work, I think you should do this instead of installing ~4 gb of programs.

Go [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio), after that, install a suitable wheel
eg:
The suitable wheel for me is PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl, as I have python 3.9(cp39) and it is a 64 bit installation(amd64).
After installing it in a directory (say, C:/docs), got to cmd and write

```
cd C:/docs
pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

This should work